# Merge multiple Images to One in multiple number of Rows and multiple number of Columns in c# Windows Form

Tags: c#, image, winforms

**Problem :** Here i want to Merge Multiple Images into One Image in one Picture-box, But the problem is that here all the Images are Merging in Horizontal shape, But i want to Merge in Multiple number of Rows and Multiple Number of Columns Shape.
**My Current App Out-Put:**
[image: Out-Put]

But here i want that all these images are adjust in 3*3 OR n*m Pattern.
**Code:**
**Button Event :**

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("F:\\Images");              
            pictureBox1.Image =  CombineBitmap(files);      `
```

`CombineBitmap(files):

```
        public static System.Drawing.Bitmap CombineBitmap(string[] files)
    {
        //read all images into memory
        List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> images = new List<System.Drawing.Bitmap>();
        System.Drawing.Bitmap finalImage = null;
        try
        {
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;
            foreach (string image in files)
            {
                //create a Bitmap from the file and add it to the list
                System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(image);
                //update the size of the final bitmap
                width += bitmap.Width;
                height = bitmap.Height > height ? bitmap.Height : height;
                images.Add(bitmap);
            }
            //create a bitmap to hold the combined image
            finalImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);
            //get a graphics object from the image so we can draw on it
            using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(finalImage))
            {
                //set background color
                g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                //go through each image and draw it on the final image
                int offset = 0;
                foreach (System.Drawing.Bitmap image in images)
                {
                    g.DrawImage(image,
                    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(offset, 0, image.Width, image.Height));
                    offset += image.Width;
                }
            }

            return finalImage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (finalImage != null)
                finalImage.Dispose();
            //throw ex;
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            //clean up memory
            foreach (System.Drawing.Bitmap image in images)
            {
                image.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }`
```

`

Comment: `new System.Drawing.Rectangle(offset, 0, image.Width, image.Height));` - You're drawing all of them at y coordinate 0.

Comment: how do you handle images of different size? or are they of the same size? And how do you handle a list of 12 images? 6 x 2 or 3 x 4 ? You need to define some rules to begin.

Comment: @kennyzx    height = bitmap.Height > height ? bitmap.Height : height; The code implies that they don't have to be the same size

Comment: Hello Sir Kennyzx, for example we have same size of images,and total Images are 36 and we want 6*6 pattren, then how we can arrange it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an additional parameter to your CombineBitmap.
This parameter express the number of columns you want to use to arrange your set of files.

Then, instead of looping with foreach you can start looping using a double for loop running on the number of columns and rows required to merge in a single image your set of files

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap CombineBitmap(string[] files, int colCount)
{
    //read all images into memory
    List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> images = new List<System.Drawing.Bitmap>();

    // Where each row starts to display the images
    List<int> YPosPerRow = new List<int>() ;
    // First row is known to be at Y position = 0 
    YPosPerRow.Add(0);

    System.Drawing.Bitmap finalImage = null;
    try
    {
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        int rowHeight = 0;
        int rowWidth = 0;

        // Calculate the number of rows required to display the files
        // per the colCount passed as argument..
        int rowCount = (files.Length / colCount) + 1;
        int index = 0;

        // Loop for each row
        for (int x = 0; x < rowCount; x++)
        {
            // Loop for each column
            for (int y = 0; y < colCount; y++)
            {
                // Should stop the loop if the bitmaps count is not
                // exactly divisible for the colCount requested
                if (index >= files.Length)
                    break;

                //create a Bitmap from the file and add it to the list
                System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(files[index]);

                // recalculate the height/width for the current row
                rowWidth += bitmap.Width;
                rowHeight = bitmap.Height > rowHeight ? bitmap.Height : rowHeight;
                images.Add(bitmap);
                index++;
            }
            // Running height
            height += rowHeight;
            // Where to put in the Y axis the next row when merging
            YPosPerRow.Add(height);

            // Running width
            width = (rowWidth > width ? rowWidth : width);

            // reset for next loop
            rowWidth = 0;
            rowHeight = 0;
        }

        //create a bitmap to hold the combined image
        finalImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);

        index = 0;
        //get a graphics object from the image so we can draw on it
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(finalImage))
        {
            //set background color
            g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);

            // Again loop over rows/columns
            for (int x = 0; x < rowCount; x++)
            {
                int offsetX = 0;
                for (int y = 0; y < colCount; y++)
                {
                    // Exit if not exactly divisible
                    if (index >= files.Length)
                        break;

                    using (Bitmap image = images[index])
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(image,
                        new System.Drawing.Rectangle(offsetX, YPosPerRow[x], image.Width, image.Height));
                        offsetX += image.Width;
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        return finalImage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (finalImage != null)
            finalImage.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        //clean up memory
        foreach (System.Drawing.Bitmap image in images)
        {
            image.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes Yes Yes . . . . . It is very good,and work best for me. Thank you very much Sir